# \listoffigures font size

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, tocloft

Can anyone tell me how I can change the font size of the `\listoffigures` content (not the caption)?

I couldn't find a corresponding option in the `tocloft` package

Answer (score 7):

The commands you are looking for are:

- `\cftloftitlefont`: controls the appeareance of the LoF title.
- `\cftfigfont`: controls the appearance of the entry (and its
  preceeding number, if any).
- `\cftfigpagefont`: This defines the font
  to be used for typesetting the page number.

Those commands can be changed using `\renewcommand`. A little example (the result is quite ugly, but it illustrates the use of the commands):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\Huge}
\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\tiny}
\renewcommand\cftfigpagefont{\Large}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering A\caption{test one}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering B\caption{test two}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the KOMA package you can use for example

```
 \setkomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries}
```

before the table of contents, and after that change the size
again with:

```
 \setkomafont{part}{<some other options...>}
```